# C++ Using pointers on structure and saving them on files

Tags: c++, file, pointers, struct

Soo i have a issue, im currently using pointers on structures and saving the values on a file

```
        struct compracli{
        char nomeartigo[50];
        char codigo[50];
        char nomecli[50];
        char data[50];
    };

int compra(int l){
compracli *ptr, d;
FILE *arquivo;
ptr = &d;

if((arquivo = fopen("compras.dat", "rb+")) !=NULL){
            //Colocar apontadores dentro dos arquivos
            system("CLS");
            cout<<"Adicinar um pedido de compra!"<<endl;
            cin.sync();
            cout<<"Adicione o nome do artigo: ";
            cin >> (*ptr).nomeartigo;
            fwrite(ptr->nomeartigo, sizeof(ptr->nomeartigo), 1, arquivo);
            cin.sync();
            cout<<"Adicione o codigo do artigo: ";
            cin >> (*ptr).codigo;
            fwrite(ptr->codigo, sizeof(ptr->codigo), 2, arquivo);
            cin.sync();
            cout<<"Adicione o nome do cliente: ";
            cin >> (*ptr).nomecli;
            fwrite(ptr->nomecli, sizeof(ptr->nomecli), 3, arquivo);
            cin.sync();
            cout<<"Adicione a data de encomenda: ";
            cin >> (*ptr).data;
            fwrite(ptr->data, sizeof(ptr->data), 4, arquivo);
            cin.sync();

            }else{
                cout<<"Erro na base de dados, de momento nao poderá aceder, tente mais tarde"<<endl;
             }
             fclose(arquivo);



  return 0;
```

The problem is, its only saving the first value, which means the (*ptr).nomeartigo . At first i thought that it was because of the buffer, maybe it was full, soo i tried to clean it using cin.sync(); But it still didnt worked out. I thought that it might be problem using the "lines" for example "fwrite(ptr->data, sizeof(ptr->data), 4, arquivo);" That "4", I thought they were saving in the same line that is why it was causing problems. But still didnt worked out! Im out of ideas, anyone knows how to?

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: Can you explain what you think this code does? For example, I see the `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` in the third parameter to `fwrite`, and I have no idea why that's there or what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This way of writting files is from C! That is why i tagged C. The third parameter supposedly was the number of lines that the value would written on the file

Comment: I'd suggest that you end every `std::cout` line with `std::endl;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cin >> (*ptr).nomeartigo;
fwrite(ptr->nomeartigo, sizeof(ptr->nomeartigo), 1, arquivo);
```

`nomeartigo` is a `char` array. This writes all the bytes in the array, including the trailing `\0` byte that `operator>>` puts there, and any uninitialized data that follows. This may or may not be wrong. Depends on how you read this back, but you did not show this code.

```
fwrite(ptr->codigo, sizeof(ptr->codigo), 2, arquivo);
```

This, and the remaining `fwrite`()s are obviously wrong.

This writes `sizeof(ptr->codigo)*2` bytes. Which is obviously not what you want. There are only `sizeof(ptr->codigo)` bytes to write here.

All the `fwrite`()s, except that first ones write too much. The third parameter to `fwrite()` is not a line number, of some kind.

Additionally, since this is C++, you should not be using `FILE *`, but rather `std::fstream`. Also, `operator>>` on a `char` array is not bound-limited, and is vulnerable to buffer overruns.

Comment: Thanks! Since i'm near the deadline, im stop using the c way and start using the fstream instead!